# Скрипт php для проверки имени+пароля

Tags: php, json

Есть форма авторизации, в которую пользователь вводит имя и пароль(данные должны храниться в json файле). Если введен имя и пароль, скрипт `php` проверяет есть ли такое имя в файле `json`, если есть то проверяет есть ли такой пароль в файле и если есть то выбить предупреждение что имя занято(не знаю как сделать так что бы проверяемый пароль относился конкретно к введенному имени). Если имя нету в файле то  происходит его запись. Запись в файл каждый раз перезаписывается, вместо того что бы дописывать новые данные(имя, пароль).  Подскажите пожалуйста как корректно сделать проверку и запись.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

if (isset($name) && isset($password)) {
    $file = 'users.json';
    $new_name = array('Name' => $name, 'Password' => $password);
    $new_name = json_encode($new_name, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, FILE_APPEND);

    file_put_contents($file, $new_name );
$fileq = file_get_contents('users.json');         

$taskList = json_decode($fileq,TRUE);
//проверяем есть ли уже такое имя в файле
if (in_array($name, $taskList)) {
    echo "Name is busy";
    //если да, то не записываем
}
else{
    echo "name is empty";
    //если нет-записываем
}
}
?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
$('#submit').click(function(){
 var name = $('#username').val();
 var password = $('#password').val();
 $.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url  : 'php/login_script.php',
  data : {user:name, pass:password}
     }); 
    });  
});
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div  id="register">
 <form method="POST" id="form">
     <p >Enter your name</p>

  <input type="text" name="username"id="username">

  <p >Enter your pasword</p>

  <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  </form>
  </div>
    <input type="Submit"  id="submit">
```

Comment: Может стоит базу данных заюзать к примеру mysql или sqllite

Comment: @Naumov в этом то и суть, что нужно что бы запись была в json файл.

Comment: Зачем так извращаться?

Comment: @Naumov такое условие

Comment: А кто ввам его поставил?

Comment: @Naumov список заданий, которые мне порекомендовал мой друг

Comment: приведи задачу так как она звучит я думаю ты просто её не понял

Comment: @Naumov Сделать простой чат с авторизацией (на файлах).пхп скрипт простой авторизации. Пользователь вводит имя и пароль, если пользователя с таки именем не существует - добавляем его в наш json файл. Если существует - сверяем пароль с сохраненным ранее. Если пароли не совпадают - сообщить об этом пользователю.

Comment: А еще принято хранить не сами пароли, а их хэши

Comment: @br3t я знаю, но конкретно в этом задании это не обязательно

Comment: Неплохая задачка. И простенькая. Повтыкай везде var_dump(имя_переменной, массива, чего угодно) и сверь поступающие / обрабатываемые данные. Скорее всего ты просто где-то запутался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл с пользователями `users.json`

```
{"user1":"pass1","user2":"pass2","user3":"pass3"}
```

Обработка

```
if(!isset($_POST['user'])||!isset($_POST['pass'])){
    echo "Username and password required";
    die();
}

$file = "users.json";
$users = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
$name = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

if(isset($users[$name]) {
    if($users[$name] === $password){
        echo "OK";
    } else {
        echo "Wrong password"
    }
} else {
    $users[$name] = $password;
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($users));
    echo "New user created";
}
```

Comment: Всё работает хорошо, только один вопрос: как после того как пользователь зарегистрировался или авторизировался осуществить переход на другую страницу `html`?

Comment: это уже совсем другой вопрос, на который не ответишь парой предложений. Вариантов там вагон и маленькая тележка. Но в любом случае изучите работу с сессиями http://php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php